# How to read dynamic named range from Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel named range defined using a function to load the unique values from a range, that is the named range is: `one_v=UNIQUE(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$23)`.
Assuming there are 3 unique values in that range, I would use in an Excel cell such a function: `Index(one_v,1)` to get the first unique value, `Index(one_v,2)` to get the second unique value and `Index(one_v,3)` to get the third distinct value.

What I try to do is to read these unique values with Python and populate a GUI drop-down list. For the sake of simplicity it would be enough to read the unique values in a Python list.

I have tried using openpyxl with destinations method but it does not work probably because the values should be returned using a function a function as mentioned above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read all the values, and then determine the unique ones in Python?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? Do you get an error message? Do you get an unexpected result (if so, what)? Please be specific. Also, please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: This is what I have tried:

def get_excel_values():
    wb = load_workbook('open_sheet.xlsx')
    named_range = wb.defined_names['Objects']
    cells_range = named_range.destinations[0][1]
    ws = wb[cells_range]

    values = [cell.value for row in ws for cell in row if cell.value is not None]
    return values

values = get_excel_values()

the error I get is:

    cells_range = named_range.destinations[0][1]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable